# Delete All Data with SQLite delete syntax?

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I've made a button that removes all the objects in my array, which is shown in my tableView. Then it reloads data and the tableview is empty. But how can I delete all the data from my SQLite database as well, and not just the array? Now the data occurs when I restart. I have tried this:

Button void:

```
   - (void) deleteAllButton_Clicked:(id)sender {

     [appDelegate removeAllBooks:nil];
     [self.tableView reloadData];


    }
```

Appdelegate void:

```
-(void) removeAllBooks:(Book *)bookObj {
 //Delete it from the database.
 [bookObj deleteAllBooks];

 //Remove it from the array.
 [bookArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Delete syntax in Book.m

```
- (void) deleteAllBooks {
 if(deleteStmt == nil) {
  const char *sql = "WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO TO DELETE ALL THE ROWS?";
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
   NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
 }

 //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
 sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, bookID);

 if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

 sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Well, the normal SQL syntax would be:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

Comment: I found out what the problem is. When I inserted NSLog into the delete syntax I didn't get any respons. This means that the appDelegate void does not send a message to book.m to perform the delete... Hm..
How can I access the deleteAllBooks method from my RootViewcontroller where my button action is?

Comment: No, I have no idea what you meant by that. The SQL that will delete all rows in the table is the one I wrote in my answer. If that is not the question, then you should clarify what you're really asking. I'm afraid I can't help you with iOS questions (or whatever NSAssert comes from.)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a standard primary id column (and you should) you can do

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id > -1;
```

And this will delete all rows in the table since there is no id less than 0.

Comment: Why not just call `DELETE FROM tablename`?

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE FROM tablename` did not work for me.  I was using a sqlite3 database on iPhone, which I assume the poster was, as well.  For me to get this to work, I needed to:

```
DROP table tablename
```

followed by a `CREATE` statement, if I wanted the table to still exist (without any rows).

Of course, that requires knowing the right `CREATE` statement.  Using the SQLManager plugin for Firefox quickly reverse-engineered for me the correct `CREATE` statement to use.  I never figured out why `DELETE FROM tablename` didn't work, but it definitely didn't, in my case.